# Can't get typescript working with partition function implemented via reduce

Tags: typescript

I took partition function found in stackoverflow. I wanted to cover it with TypeScript, but have some problems. Idea is that function accepts array of multiple types (`type DataItem = InputItem | CheckboxItem;`) but returns array of `InputItem[]` and `CheckboxItem[]` which is passed to generic.

Unfortunately I am getting TS error inside reduce:

> 'R1' could be instantiated with an arbitrary type which could be
> unrelated to 'R1 | T'.(2345)

And I don't have any idea how to fix it.

Here is code (also [StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/typescript-vz5g1a?file=index.ts) example)

```
function partition<R1, R2, T = R1 | R2>(
  array: T[],
  isValid: (element: T) => boolean
): [R1[], R2[]] {
  const result = array.reduce<[R1[], R2[]]>(
    ([pass, fail], elem) => {
      return isValid(elem) ? [[...pass, elem], fail] : [pass, [...fail, elem]];
    },
    [[], []]
  );
  return result;
}

type InputItem = {
  type: 'input';
  label: string;
  value: string;
};

type CheckboxItem = {
  type: 'checkbox';
  label: string;
  value: boolean;
};


type DataItem = InputItem | CheckboxItem;

const data: DataItem[] = [
  { type: 'input', label: 'Input 1', value: '' },
  { type: 'checkbox', label: 'Checkbox 1', value: true },
];

const [checkboxes, inputs] = partition<CheckboxItem, InputItem>(
  data,
  (item) => item.type === 'checkbox'
);

console.log('checkboxes:', checkboxes);
console.log('inputs:', inputs);
```

Comment: Your `T` type parameter is superfluous and should be removed; it's only complicating things and the problem remains when you remove it; could you [edit] to do so? Once you do that: the compiler has no reason to believe that `isValid()` will narrow its input type; it just returns `boolean` (the *name* `isValid` doesn't mean anything to the compiler). If you mark it as a type guard function (and then you have to pass such a function in when you call it) like [this](//tsplay.dev/wRz47w) then it works.  Does that fully address the question? If so I'll write up an answer; if not, what am I missing?

Comment: @jcalz Oh, thank you. It works. And there is no way to avoid `item is CheckboxItem` where function is used? P.S. If you post as an answer I will mark it as solution

Comment: You can certainly avoid it, but then you need to tell the compiler that, inside the function,  `isValid` behaves as a type guard, via a type assertion like [this](https://tsplay.dev/WokLMW).  Should I add that to the answer?  ... and could you [edit] to remove `T` as shown [here](https://tsplay.dev/w2pd1m)?  Or I can do it if you'd prefer.

Comment: @jcalz This is a very interesting case and I believe can be valuable as a full answer.